# Can't read cookie using angularJS && WebApi

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I was trying to make a register function using angularJS and webAPI
After registering , API should set a cookie. However when I reload the page there is no cookie! I don't know what is the problem!!!!

This is how I set the cookie

```
 public HttpResponseMessage register(User UserToRegister)
    {
        UserToRegister.UserID = Guid.NewGuid();
        YanceySiteDBEntities db = new YanceySiteDBEntities();
        db.Users.Add(UserToRegister);
        db.SaveChanges();

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, UserToRegister);
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("useremail", UserToRegister.UserEmail);
        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookie.Path = "/";
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        return response;
    }
```

And this is how I read the cookie.

```
 public bool CheckIfLogIn()
    {
        bool LogedIn = false;
        CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("useremail").FirstOrDefault();
        if (cookie != null) LogedIn = true;

        return LogedIn;
    }
```

Hope anyone can help me , Thanks in advance!